# modpost.h:12:23: fatal error: elfconfig.h: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, kernel, compiling

I am running Ubuntu:

```
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Kernel info:

3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:23:47 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

The source that I am having is :
**linux-lts-raring-3.8.0**

When I am trying to make my first driver I get the following errors:

```
make -C /usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0 SUBDIRS=/home/drdr/Documents/drivers/first_driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: not found
make[2]: *** [__modpost] Error 127
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Then I went to scripts/mod/ in my source directory I typed make:

```
root@drdr:/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0/scripts/mod# make modpost
cc     modpost.c   -o modpost
In file included from modpost.c:18:0:
modpost.h:12:23: fatal error: elfconfig.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
make: *** [modpost] Error 1
```

**Update**
I found a related file mk_elfconfig.c. Is there a way to generate elfconfig.h from this;

```
root@drdr:/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0/scripts/mod# ls -ld mk_elfconfig.c 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 1234 Feb 19  2013 mk_elfconfig.c
```

Why I am getting this error? I believe the version of the source code  and what is running are the same.

The Makefile and source code for the driver is given [here](http://www.opensourceforu.com/2010/12/writing-your-first-linux-driver/)

**Update**
after copying config- from /boot to my source code as .config:
I did

```
root@drdr:/home/drdr/Documents/drivers/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0#make oldconfig 
scripts/kconfig/conf --oldconfig Kconfig
#
# configuration written to .config
#

root@drdr:/home/drdr/Documents/drivers/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0# make prepare
scripts/kconfig/conf --silentoldconfig Kconfig
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_32.h
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_64.h
  SYSHDR  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/uapi/asm/unistd_x32.h
  SYSTBL  arch/x86/syscalls/../include/generated/asm/syscalls_32.h
  HOSTCC  arch/x86/tools/relocs
  WRAP    arch/x86/include/generated/asm/clkdev.h
  CHK     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  UPD     include/generated/uapi/linux/version.h
  CHK     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  UPD     include/generated/utsrelease.h
  CC      kernel/bounds.s
  GEN     include/generated/bounds.h
  CC      arch/x86/kernel/asm-offsets.s
  GEN     include/generated/asm-offsets.h
  CALL    scripts/checksyscalls.sh
root@drdr:/home/drd/Documents/drivers/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0#
```

But still same error in driver compilation:

```
root@drdr:/home/drdr/Documents/drivers/first_driver# make
make -C /usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0 SUBDIRS=/home/drdr/Documents/drivers/first_driver modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0'

  WARNING: Symbol version dump /usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0/Module.symvers
           is missing; modules will have no dependencies and modversions.

  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
/bin/sh: 1: scripts/mod/modpost: not found
make[2]: *** [__modpost] Error 127
make[1]: *** [modules] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0'
make: *** [default] Error 2
```

Comment: Did you do `make config` and `make prepare` inside the kernel source tree?

Comment: @AndreasWiese I think yes, let me try again.

Comment: @AndreasWiese I gave make config and it started question/answer ,and I know it would ask 100s of such question. I dont have so much petaince..so any alternative where it would not ask questions?

Comment: Copy your running kernel's config (found in `/proc/config.gz` or `/boot/config-<kernelversion>`) to `.config` in the kernel source and do `make oldconfig`.

Comment: @AndreasWiese Did that. Kindly see the update

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly what you unpacked in `/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0`, but:

- It's probably not what you need.
- The location is really weird, you shouldn't be creating directories directly under `/usr`.

To compile a kernel module, what you need is the headers plus a few more files produced by compiling the kernel with the same configuration. See [Unable to load module: Disagrees about version of symbol module_layout](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125624/unable-to-load-module-disagrees-about-version-of-symbol-module-layout/125707#125707) for a more complete explanation.

Remove this `/usr/linux-lts-raring-3.8.0` and instead install the kernel headers package corresponding to your runing kernel: for example, if your running kernel is from the `linux-image-3.8.0-38-generic` package, then install the `linux-headers-3.8.0-38-generic` package.

To compile a module against a particular Debian/Ubuntu/… kernel version such as `linux-headers-3.8.0-38-generic`, go to the module directory and run

```
make -C /usr/src/linux-headers-3.8.0-38-generic M=$PWD
```

To compile a module against the running kernel, make sure that the appropriate kernel headers package is installed and run

```
make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=$PWD
```

I recommend reading [`kbuild/modules.tt`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/kbuild/modules.txt) in the kernel documentation.

Comment: To add to Giles Answer: If you till want to use `linux-lts-raring-3.8.0`, you're going to need to compile it against the linux-headers for kernel 3.8.0