# Ubuntu kernel source code package

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, source

Can somebody explain me the difference between the following files:

```
drwxr-xr-x  28 root root      4096 Apr 22 12:04 linux-lts-raring-3.8.0
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  15209788 Mar 14 03:38 linux-lts-raring_3.8.0-38.56~precise1.diff.gz
-rw-r--r--   1 root root      6333 Mar 14 03:38 linux-lts-raring_3.8.0-38.56~precise1.dsc
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 107018407 May  8  2013 linux-lts-raring_3.8.0.orig.tar.gz
```

I want to write a simple driver and so would give the path of one of these in my driver Makefile.

**OS Info**

```
#lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
```

Also:

```
3.8.0-38-generic #56~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 13 16:23:47 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

Answer (score 3):

What you present in your first listing are one directory (at the top, line starting with `d` is the giveaway) and 3 files. Of the files the last one looks like a Linux source tree for Ubuntu 13.04, the first a diff (difference between the previous source tree and Ubuntu 12.04. The `.dsc` file is the metadata for the first file.

In your Makefile you are unlikely to have to point to any of those **files**, but you might have to have it point to the directory if that contains the unpacked `.tar.gz` with the `.diff` applied.

Comment: "have to to the"?

Comment: @FaheemMitha there was "point" missing there, thanks

Answer (score 1):

A source package in Debian and derivatives (Ubuntu, Mint, …) consists of three files:

- `NAME_VERSION.orig.tar.gz` is the original (upstream) source code.
- `NAME_VERSION-REVISION.diff.gz` or `NAME_VERSION-REVISION.debian.tar.gz` is the patch applied by Debian.
- `NAME_VERSION-REVISION.dsc` is a small text file that contains some metadata about the other files.

*VERSION* is the upstream version number and *REVISION*. See [the Debian policy manual](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-controlfields.html#s-f-Version) for more information about package versions.

For packages maintained directly by Debian or a derivative, there is no `.diff.gz` or `.debian.tar.gz` file, and no `-REVISION` component in the package version.

---

What you have here is a kernel source package. The `lts-raring` package is a backport of the kernel from Ubuntu 13.04 raring to the previous long-time support version, Ubuntu 12.04 precise.

The kernel source is what you need if you want to browse the kernel source or to recompile a kernel with different compilation options or different patches. It is not what you need to compile external modules. See [modpost.h:12:23: fatal error: elfconfig.h: No such file or directory](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/125925/modpost-h1223-fatal-error-elfconfig-h-no-such-file-or-directory/126045#126045)